# How can I dismiss UITableViewController popover and update outlet on OtherViewController after selecting a cell?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode4.3, popover

I currently have a popover that is a UITableViewController (called `TableViewController`) with 4 cells. Upon selecting one of the cells I would like to dismiss the popover and at the same time take a variable that is set based on the cell selection and use it as the text in a label outlet (i.e. `self.styleText.text = thePopoverCellVariable;`) in my other View Controller (called `OtherViewController`). How can I do this?

Right now this only works if I dismiss the popover by clicking outside. The code in the `TableViewController.m` is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ((OtherViewController *)self.presentingViewController).thePopoverCellVariable=theVariable;
}
```

And in `OtherViewController.m`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue;
    popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;

    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
    popoverController.delegate=self;
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    thePopoverCellVariable = ((StyleViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController).theVariable;
    self.styleText.text=thePopoverCellVariable;
}
```

Comment: I can get this to work when I click outside of (dismiss) the popover but not upon clicking the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **finally** figured this out. @Jeffery Thomas has 99% of the correct answer. The other 1% is that you have to dismiss the popover from the root view controller, in this case `OtherViewController`. So I made `popoverController` a variable in the header file and implemented my code as follows

```
//OtherViewController.m
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue;
    popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
    popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
    pCVisible = YES;
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
}

- (void) setDataFromPopover {
    if (pCVisible) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; // THIS IS KEY! this is where the popover is dismissed, not in the popover itself
    }
}
```

And...

```
//TableViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //variable = whatever

    OtherViewController *initialView;
    initialView=(OtherViewController *)self.delegate;
    initialView.theLabel.text = variable;
    [initialView setDataFromPopover];
}
```

Comment: I could not get this to work... problem with the setDelegate method. I finally used a singleton to pass all data. Plain and simple :)

Comment: Build error: Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'OperateRoomList *'. How to declare delegate?

Comment: @Sucrenoir I want to set the UIPopoverController value to a singleton's `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController* popover;
`, but failed:-[MLControl setPopover:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffe61d32520
2014-12-19 18:07:36.844 Medical CRM[62844:4286627] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MLControl setPopover:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffe61d32520'

Answer (score 0):

In `TableViewController`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popoverController; // In header

@synthesize popoverController = _popoverController;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.theVariable = … // get the variable from the cell.

    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

In `OtherViewController`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue;
    popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;

    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
    popoverController.delegate=self;

    TableViewController *tableViewController = (TableViewController *)popoverSegue.destinationViewController;
    tableViewController.popoverController = popoverController;
}
```

---

Sorry for the confusion earlier, I thought this would work like a modal view controller.

---

OK, I don't think this is optimal, but it should work.

---

**Update**

`-popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` would not get called if you haven't set `popoverController.delegate = self` in `OtherViewController` (see: [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/delegate)). This could be done in the storyboard or in `-prepareForSegue:sender:`

Comment: I just implemented that code and ran it, and it doesn't do anything. :(

Comment: @lemontwist Sorry, I'm not totally familiar with UIPopoverController. I updated the code with something that I hope might work. The basic logic should hold. You can know which row was clicked on in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. How you pass that from OtherViewController to TableViewController it the tricky part.

Comment: That's OK. The variable I can get over to the other view controller. I just can't get the popover to go away when I click on the cell. I tried this new code and it also didn't cause the popover to dismiss upon clicking.

Comment: @lemontwist Well this should work for sure. Add a popoverController property to the TableViewController and set it in the `-prepareForSegue:`.

Comment: Hmm... now the popover is being dismissed when I click the cell, but the variable isn't passing properly to `OtherViewController`.

Comment: I put an `NSLog(@"%@",thePopoverCellVariable);` in the `OtherViewController.m` function `(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController`, and it never shows up, which leads me to believe that function is not being used.

Comment: Another thing that might complicate this is that I hope to have 2 popovers used to obtain data from the user in table format.

Comment: @lemontwist make sure you have set the delegate, see my update.